# Asp.net EntityFrameworkCore table relation

Tags: asp.net

I wrote the following code in ASP.NET core. I want to establish a connection between the tables `Post` and `Interview` over `interview_id` column. How can I do that?

```
public class Post { 
    [Display(Name = "Post Title")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public long interview_id { get; set; }
    public int visa_type_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
    public string story { get; set; }
    public bool gotten { get; set; }
}

public class Interview {
    [Display(Name = "Post Title")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int interview_id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
    public string answer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: are you using entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want relation one to one, you just must add related entities in your tables classes:

```
public class Post
{
    public long interview_id { get; set; }
    public Interview Interview { get; set; }
}

// if you want two way relation
public class Interview
{
    public long post_id { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```